# send model form as a json response in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to send a **modelform** to my template using through **json response**(I've no idea if it's possible or not).

Actually in my template I have a list of objects from a model, and when i click them i send a post request to my view through ajax or axios with the object id, then in view I'm creating the model form of that object and I want to send that the model form of instance object back to template.

to summarize it up how can i **send an model form through json response**.(If not possible how to )

**updated!**

this is my `forms.py`

```
...
class UpdateMedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalRecords
        fields = ("title", "file", "doctor", "doctor_access", "general_access")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": "", "class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Optional"}),
            "file": forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "doctor": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }
        labels = {
            "title": "Description (Optional)",
            "general_access": "General Access For Record",
            "doctor_access": "Doctor Access For Record",
        }
```

then in `views.py` i'm getting the `medicalrecord, ID` through the ajax and make a `UpdateMedicalRecordForm()` modelform for that instance as

```
from_instace = UpdateMedicalRecordForm(
    request.POST, request.FILES,
    instance=get_object_or_404(MedicalRecords, id=request.POST.get("file-id"))
)
```

here i don't know how to send my response back to template, to use it as form.as_p or loop through that.

```
...
JsonResponse({
   "form": ??
})
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: thanks for replay, I updated that's how my code is.

Comment: you can send the data of your form in json then construct your form with js

Comment: thanks Sir **@belhadjerSamir** , I'm trying this and  as I'm new to django could you give me a guidance on how to perform, or links for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

you can use django-remote-forms like this :

```
    from django_remote_forms.forms import RemoteForm
    from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

    ####
    form = UpdateMedicalRecordForm(
        request.POST, request.FILES,
        instance=get_object_or_404(MedicalRecords, id=request.POST.get("file-id"))
    )
form['instance']=model_to_dict(form['instance'])
    remote_form = RemoteForm(form)
    remote_form_dict = remote_form.as_dict()
    response = HttpResponse(
        json.simplejson.dumps(remote_form_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
        mimetype="application/json"
    )

    # Process response for CSRF
    csrf_middleware.process_response(request, response)
    return response
```

then you can parse the response in you js

Comment: I still get **Object of type FieldFile is not JSON serializable**.

Comment: I've no idea still the same **Object of type FieldFile is not JSON serializable.** :(

Comment: the problem is the file field in your form

Comment: I just removed file filed from my form, It's what I am getting now  **Object of type ModelChoiceIteratorValue is not JSON serializable**

Comment: In your case your form contains a mix of django objects and dicts inside.

Comment: I've no idea about and struggling with this almost 3days..

Comment: try my modification